# error 'for' statement doesn't loop en webstorm al usar for of

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, ecmascript-6

Al iterar con la sentencia: "for of" sobre un arreglo, webstorm me arroja el siguiente error:

'for' statement doesn't loop.

Este es mi código:

```js
for (const { type } of files) {
   return this.allowedFiles.includes(type)
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu error esta en const { type }, no debería ser type of files?, deberías poner mas código para tener mas contexto y poder ayudarte

Comment: Lo que te está diciendo es que tu ciclo, no es un ciclo! Imagina que tú eres V8 o cualquier otro motor js, y te piden ejecutar ese código. Vas a entrar a la primera iteración y después vas a retornar inmediatamente un valor. ¿Cuándo entras a la siguiente iteración? nunca!

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán tienes razón al remover el return el error desaparece, Gracias!!